# Two dimensional continuous function - Continuity of maximizer?

Tags: optimization, continuity

I already asked a similar question but now recognized I need a different property.

Is the following statement correct?

> Given a continuous function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$ and $g(x)$ such that
>   $f(x,g(x))> f(x,z)$ for all $z\geq 0$,
>   then $g(x)$ is continuous.

I hope you can understand the statement. Perhaps the result is some basic Lemma I am not aware of :-(

Thanks for all answers so far. I missed to give you one piece of information: $g(x)$ is the unique maximizer (I changed the statement accordingly).

Comment: Isn't $f \equiv 42$ a counterexample?

Comment: For a nontrivial counterexample, consider $f(x,y)=(\sin y)^2e^{-(x-y)^2}$.

Comment: My answer to your last question also immediately answers this question.

Comment: Thx to all three! Unfortunately I missed an important information for you, so that imo all your counterexamples do not work any longer